# How to call web-service call in PHP when click on login button

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, web-services, dom-events

I am a newbie to the Web-service area.
My question is I am using web service for login.  When user click on login button, I have to call web-service and if web-service give me success reply then user go to home page.

I am confused with what to do; whether use on-click method means user click on login button call Javascript function which having call for web-service or any other thing available in PHP i.e. how to call in PHP when user click on login button, because after success I have to transfer user on homepage.

Then which method I have to follow:

1. use JavaScript call for web service OR
2. use PHP call for web-service but I don't know how to call when user click on button

because i want set session for user , when i use java-script function then how the userid is pass to php for storing in the session.

i am using codeigniter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a php guy but this might help you make a better decision:
As you said you have two options:

Option 1: (Bad Idea)
1. User Clicks login button
2. A JavaScript method is called, which makes a Ajax Call to authentication service
3. If authenticated, you redirect user to Home page

Option 2:
1. On Login click, you take the user to a controller.
2. Controller calls authentication
3. Responses with a redirect if successful.

Now why i say option 1 is bad idea because doing it in JS has potential threat, as some one can bypass the authentication to  get access to login.

So doing it as you said with a 'php' call is a better idea.